# Understanding "Bitwise-And (&)" and "Unary complement(~)" in c++

Tags: c++, c, bitwise-operators, logical-operators

I have some trouble understanding `Bitwise-And`  and  `Unary Complement` when both are used in this code snippet

```
if((oldByte==m_DLE) & (newByte==m_STX)) {
    int data_index=0;

   //This below line --- does it returns true if both the oldByte and newByte are not true 
   //and within timeout 
while((timeout.read_s()<m_timeout) & ~((oldByte==m_DLE) & (newByte==m_ETX))) { 

                        if(Serial.available()>0) {
                            oldByte=newByte;
                            newByte=Serial.read();

                            if(newByte==m_DLE) {
                            .
                            .
                            .
```

are the both operators `& ~`are performing a logical not operation like checking until if both `oldByte` and `newByte` are false

The above code is from the [link](https://github.com/GraemeWilson/Arduino-Python-Framing-CRC16/blob/af28e4c5106505c7d1227bf840fef55db0f679af/Arduino/Framing.cpp)  --> line 227 of the code

I am  trying to use the implement the code for my application in C but without the timing functions

```
 if((oldByte==DLE) && (newByte== STX)) {
    data_index = 0;
     // is this the correct implematation for above C++ code to C  
    while(! ((oldByte== DLE) && (newByte== ETX))){
          oldByte = newByte;
```

Is this method correct for implementing in C

Comment: Ask the programmer obfuscating the code. (Several & look like a logically &&)

Comment: @DieterLücking -- I tried, but no response .. kinda old post on GitHub

Comment: c & c++ are not the same language.  The tag (when correctly set) is intended to save time.

Comment: This code was either deliberately made to be confusing, or the person who made it was completely clueless, and it works thanks to BAD luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
(timeout.read_s()<m_timeout) & ~((oldByte==m_DLE) & (newByte==m_ETX))
```

is equivalent to (but probably less readable than)

```
(timeout.read_s()<m_timeout) && !(oldByte==m_DLE && newByte==m_ETX)
```

which is equivalent to (and IMO less readable than)

```
(timeout.read_s()<m_timeout) && (oldByte!=m_DLE || newByte!=m_ETX)
```

Edit: should add a caveat about short-circuiting. Although the particular example statements will all return the same value, using && or || will skip evaluating pieces that can't impact the result. This isn't important in your specific example, but could be very important in an example like this:

```
(oldByte!=nullptr & *oldByte == m_ETX) // will crash when oldByte=nullptr.

(oldByte!=nullptr && *oldByte == m_ETX) // will evaluate to false when oldByte=nullptr.
```

Answer (score 2):

Since the equality-operator (==) yields 0 or 1 as a result, you can use bitwise and, too. (foo==1) & ~(bar==1) works too, since the AND with (foo==1), which always results in 1 and 0, masks all other bits in ~(bar==1). However, it is strongly recommended to use the logical counterparts &&, || and !.

The following would not work as expected:

```
if (~(bar == 1) & ~(foo == 1))
```

e.g. if foo = bar = 1, then it would evaluate to 0xfffffffe on ia32, which is different from 0 and therefore "TRUE"